# Compound Statements with Overloaded operators not working(C++)

Tags: c++, class, reference, operator-overloading

I am making a class Matrix in c++ but in testing, I found that statements like

```
cout << M1;    //M1 is object of class Matrix
```

are working but the others like

```
cout << M1 + M2;    //M1 and M2 of class matrix
```

are giving me errors. My concerned overloaded functions have these prototypes:

```
//for matrix addition
Matrix operator+(Matrix& m)

//for stream insertion operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Matrix & m)
```

Can you guys help me where I am going wrong? I can post the actual code if it's required.

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix & m)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temporaries cannot bind to non-const lvalue references. This is a temporary:

```
M1 + M2
```

and your operator takes a non-const reference as 2nd parameter. You can fix this by changing it to `const`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix & m)
```

While you're at it, you can change the parameter of `operator+` and make it const. It makes no sense for `operator+` to modify either operand:

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& m) const
```

Comment: Hmm that solves the problem.  Thank you for pointing it out (y)

Comment: I really forgot to make it constant in operator+. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the operator like

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix & m );
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem is that this operator

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix& m);
```

returns a temporary object and tenporary object may not be bound with a non-constant reference.